# How to selectively replace a group of three characters using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace three specific characters (triplet) in a text.
I want to match a pattern starting at position 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 etc. but not at position 2, 3, 5, 6 etc.

E.g., I want to look/replace `taa` with `NNN` in the text `ctaagctaaggcgtaaga`, and I want to get `ctaagcNNNggcgtaaga`.

The first occurrence of 'taa' starts at position 2 and should not be matched/replaced, the second occurrence starts at position 7 and is replaced, the third occurrence starts at position 14 and is not matched.

---

My solution so far is to separate triplets by '+', do the replacement and remove all '+'. However, I am thinking about more elegant solution with single sed command.

```
echo $dna | sed 's/.../&+/g;s/+$//' | sed 's/taa/NNN/g' | sed 's/+//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will need more than one `sed` command to accomplish this.
You can however do all of the command in one invocation of `sed`, e.g.:

```
<<<ctaagctaaggcgtaaga bsdsed 's/.../&+/g; s/taa/NNN/g; s/+//g'
```

Output:

```
ctaagcNNNggcgtaaga
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single `s` command:

```
sed 's/^\(\(...\)*\)taa/\1NNN/g'
```

Note that the match is anchored to the beginning of the string, and that the `taa` must be preceded by a whole number of character triplets.  The triplets are just subbed for themselves.

Example use:

```
sed 's/^\(\(...\)*\)taa/\1NNN/g' <<EOF
ctaagctaaggcgtaaga
EOF
```

Output:

```
ctaagcNNNggcgtaaga
```

Answer (score 0):

with GNU `sed`

```
echo ctaagctaaggcgtaaga | sed 's/taa/NNN/2'

ctaagcNNNggcgtaaga
```

this replaced the second instance, but I missed the actual requirement.  The following only replaces the triples in correct positions

```
echo ctaagctaaggcgtaaga | 
fold -w3 | 
sed 's/taa/NNN/' | 
tr -d '\n'; echo ""

ctaagcNNNggcgtaaga
```

Comment: That's wrong .... for example `"taacgctaaggcgtaaga"` should give `"NNNcgcNNNggcgtaaga"`

Comment: `tr` eats up all newlines, `echo` puts the last one back.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^((...)*)taa/\1NNN/;ta' file
```

This works back from the end of the line matching in threes and repeats untill all matches have been made.